# Default props not set for ES6 function as default value

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I've found that my default properties are not set when the default value is an ES6 imported function:

```
import { noop } from '../helpers';
//...
static defaultProps = {
onCancel: noop
}
// or
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
onCancel: noop
}
```

**/helpers.js**

```
export const noop = () => {};
```

And somewhere in component

```
this.props.onCancel();
```

will throw: `Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.onCancel is not a function`

Placing `console.log(this.props.onCancel);` logs `undefined`

However if I will change the signature of `noop` to be `export function noop () {};`

then it works. Also if I'm not importing this placeholder function but define it in the component file then it also works.

```
const noop = () => {};
//...
static defaultProps = {
onCancel: noop
}
// or
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
onCancel: noop
}
```

Also if I put `console.log(noop);` I do receive `ƒ noop() {}` in the output so the function IS imported to the file.

What is the problem with my first approach?

Comment: What is the output if you attempt to log `this.props.onCancel` immediately before firing it?

Comment: It outputs `undefined`

Comment: `undefined` is not a function ahah Your `export` / `import` statements are probably not matching up

Comment: I've updated Q with more details, but no, if I log the imported `noop` function then I have a body of the function.

Comment: try `export function noop () {};`

Comment: @DavidLin for OP your solution is working but if he uses arrow function then it does not work

Comment: Ok, fair. In that case I'd guess the problem is to do with the scope of `this`. I'm not able to replicate it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you have some circular dependency, so at compile time the exports from `../helpers` are no available, even though they will be available at runtime.

So if you try to use your `noop` somewhere inside a method of the class, it will work fine: Eg:

```
import { noop } from '../helpers';

class Button extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        onCancel: noop // not available here, as this is assigned at compilation time
    }

    handleButtonClick(event) {
        noop() // available here, as this is called at runtime
    }


}
```

you can verify the above by doing:

```
import * as helps from '../helpers';

console.log(helpers)
```

you will notice that the helpers object points to undefined attributes

You can try the following Webpack plugin to find our circular dependency:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin

PS: if you have not ejected your create-react project, `git checkout -b` to another branch, eject and add the plugin, find the circular dependency.